# Can I use two google-services json files from different google projects?

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, google-play-services, google-api-console

I have two google accounts, first is for Notifications and second is for Google sign in. For implementing this two services I  should add two configuration files in my android application, but i can't do that because google does not support that. I had searched in google, there are people who recommend to use flavors, but I can't do that. So I think about merging two `google-services.json` files. Or should I remove 
one of google accounts and create new one in second account. What should I do?

Comment: Out of interest, what approach did you end up taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use single google account. You can use both Google sign  in and Notifications api in single account.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible, you have to choose second option, you need to use one google project for different google services

Answer (score 1):

Google does document several approaches to support multiple sets of `google-services.json` parameters, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

From what you've asked,the best option may be to create your own firebase object https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application However, they explain some of the risks and limitations of having multiple sets of parameters in https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#reliable-analytics

They also provide helpful documentation on how the file is processed https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file which may help you especially if you decide to merge the contents of several `google-services.json` files.

Out of interest, what approach did you end up taking?